# Dynamically setting a core data key/value pair

Tags: ios, core-data

I know this should be possible but I'm having trouble finding the right API to do this.

Lets say i have the attributes in a given Entity:

- atr1
- atr2
- atr3

And I want to "dynamically" set an attribute.  For example if I had the following code block:

```
 NSString *attributeToSet = @"atr2"
 int newValue = 3
```

Is there some call like:

```
 [NSManagedObject setAttribute:attributeToSet newValue:newValue]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the template code that's generated for the default master/detail type of application.  It contains the following code sample:

```
// Normally you should use accessor methods, but using KVC here avoids the need to add a custom class to the template.
[newManagedObject setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"timeStamp"];
```

The `key` corresponds to an entity property that you've defined.